# CentOS7 Remi-PHP81 Followed steps. PHP command not found

Tags: php, centos7, rpm

Trying to install and enable PHP in a CentOS VPS. Found repository information from Remi's RPM Repository - Configuration wizard. Followed steps to install and enable PHP81. But php -v gives command not found error.

yum repolist shows remi-php81.

Is there anymore configurations to be updated like PATH variable?

Comment: Have you install php-cli ?  (a list of installed package may help)

Comment: Thank you. Installed using 'yum install php'. Version now available.